# Uploading a Azure blob directly to SFTP server without an intermediate file

Tags: c#, .net, sftp, azure-blob-storage, ssh.net

I'm attempting to upload am Azure blob directly to an SFTP server.

It's simple to upload a file from a local location:

```
using (var sftp = new SftpClient(connectionInfo)){
    sftp.Connect();
    using (var uplfileStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(fileName)){
        sftp.UploadFile(uplfileStream, fileName, true);
    }
    sftp.Disconnect();
}
```

Is there a way to copy blobs from blob storage directly to an SFTP server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Either combine [`CloudBlob.OpenRead`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.storage.blob.cloudblob.openread) with `SftpClient.UploadFile`:

   ```
   using (var blobReadStream = blockBlob.OpenRead())
   {
       sftp.UploadFile(blobReadStream, remotePath, true);
   }
   ```
2. Or combine `SftpClient.Create` with  [`CloudBlob.DownloadToStream`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.storage.blob.cloudblob.downloadtostream):

   ```
   using (var sftpWriteStream = sftp.Create(remotePath))
   {
       blockBlob.DownloadToStream(sftpWriteStream);
   }
   ```

The first approach should be a way faster in SFTP terms, as `SftpClient.UploadFile` is optimized, comparing to the `SftpFileStream` returned by `SftpClient.Create`.