# Upload xml file to Azure FTP folder using C#

Tags: c#, azure, ftp

I am looking to upload a XML file that is generated using C# to a ftp folder that is in Azure Server. what ways you are suggesting?

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a good site to come to if you have no idea how to get started. Did you try reading the appropriate documentation? Implementing the code? What stopped your implementation from succeeding?

Comment: One of the workarounds is to use Create File connector with FTP and upload file by uploading the actual file from the local machine to sharepoint/blob storage and adding the file from there. Also, try checking this https://www.codeproject.com/questions/543908/uploadplusfileplustoplusftpplusfromplusblobplussto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are few options that you can give it a try

- One of the workarounds that we can try is to use Create File connector with FTP in **Logic Apps** and upload file by uploading the actual file from the local machine to sharepoint/blob storage and adding the file from there.
- Else we can upload the file from blob to ftp server through C#. For more information on this please refer [Upload file to ftp from blob storage. - CodeProject](https://www.codeproject.com/questions/543908/uploadplusfileplustoplusftpplusfromplusblobplussto)

**REFERENCES:**
[c# - Uploading a Azure blob directly to SFTP server without an intermediate file - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57065811/uploading-a-azure-blob-directly-to-sftp-server-without-an-intermediate-file).